# How to count the total number of check box checked value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

we need to add the total number of check box checked count value in element.

But when we checked the check box in "heading 2" part , the checked count value was added in "heading 1" part .

I did not find the issue any one please guide me resolve this issue

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/gqcgwjq2/2/)

**HTMl:**

```
    <div id="main">


    <div class="a">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-12 cb_select_head">
                    <a data-parent="#accordion" data-toggle="collapse" href="#function-collapse"><span class=
                                    "glyphicon ecm-caret-down"></span></a><span class="labelBlock labelCounter">
                                    <span class="count-checked-checkboxes">0</span></span>
                    <span class="fb_options_head">heading 1</span>
                  </div>
                  <ul class="sidebar fb-list-option collapse in" id="function-collapse">
                    <li><a href="" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Actuarial-collapse"><span class="glyphicon ecm-caret-right"></span></a>
                      <input id="c1" name="cc" type="checkbox">
                      <label for="c1">asdas</label>

                    </li>
                    <li class="noArrow">
                      <input id="c2" name="cc" type="checkbox">
                      <label for="c2">asdasd</label>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="" data-toggle="collapse"><span class="glyphicon ecm-caret-right"></span></a>
                      <input id="c3" name="cc" type="checkbox">
                      <label for="c3">asdasd
                      </label>

                      <ul>
                                    <li><input id="c1" name="cc" type="checkbox"><label for="c1">asd 1</label></li>
                                    <li><input id="c1" name="cc" type="checkbox"><label for="c1">sadas 2</label></li>
                                    <li><input id="c1" name="cc" type="checkbox"><label for="c1">asdas 3</label></li>
                                    </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="" data-toggle="collapse"><span class="glyphicon ecm-caret-right"></span></a>
                      <input id="c4" name="cc" type="checkbox">
                      <label for="c4">asdasd</label>
                    </li>
                    <li class="noArrow">
                      <input id="c5" name="cc" type="checkbox">
                      <label for="c5">five</label>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
          <!--First List End-->

          <!--Second list start -->

             <div class="a">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-12 cb_select_head">
                    <a data-parent="#accordion" data-toggle="collapse" href="#function-collapse"><span class=
                                    "glyphicon ecm-caret-down"></span></a><span class="labelBlock labelCounter">
                                    <span class="count-checked-checkboxes">0</span></span>
                    <span class="fb_options_head">heading 2</span>
                  </div>
                  <ul class="sidebar fb-list-option collapse in" id="function-collapse">
                    <li><a href="" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Actuarial-collapse"><span class="glyphicon ecm-caret-right"></span></a>
                      <input id="c1" name="cc" type="checkbox">
                      <label for="c1">asdas</label>

                    </li>
                    <li class="noArrow">
                      <input id="c2" name="cc" type="checkbox">
                      <label for="c2">asdasd</label>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="" data-toggle="collapse"><span class="glyphicon ecm-caret-right"></span></a>
                      <input id="c3" name="cc" type="checkbox">
                      <label for="c3">asdasd
                      </label>

                      <ul>
                                    <li><input id="c1" name="cc" type="checkbox"><label for="c1">asd 1</label></li>
                                    <li><input id="c1" name="cc" type="checkbox"><label for="c1">sadas 2</label></li>
                                    <li><input id="c1" name="cc" type="checkbox"><label for="c1">asdas 3</label></li>
                                    </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="" data-toggle="collapse"><span class="glyphicon ecm-caret-right"></span></a>
                      <input id="c4" name="cc" type="checkbox">
                      <label for="c4">asdasd</label>
                    </li>
                    <li class="noArrow">
                      <input id="c5" name="cc" type="checkbox">
                      <label for="c5">five</label>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>  


 </div>
```

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $checkboxes = $(
        '#main ul input[type="checkbox"]');
    $checkboxes.change(function() {
        var countCheckedCheckboxes = $checkboxes.filter(
            ':checked').length;
        $('.count-checked-checkboxes').text(
            countCheckedCheckboxes);
        $('#edit-count-checked-checkboxes').val(
            countCheckedCheckboxes);
    });
});
```

Comment: You have the ul tags declared with the same id value. You need to declare them with seperate ids

Comment: @DinoMyte : The id ("#main") for parent div

Comment: @DinoMyte: we need to change the id for each <ul> ?

Comment: @Mgr Yeah you can do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use the `this` reference to find the context of our selector. I have used the `closest(".row")` to find the context here. After that, we have to select the checked checkboxes inside the found context and update the values.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(":checkbox").change(function() {
  var closest = $(this).closest("div.row");
    var countCheckedCheckboxes = $(":checkbox", closest).filter(':checked').length;
    $('.count-checked-checkboxes', closest).text(countCheckedCheckboxes);
    $('#edit-count-checked-checkboxes').val(countCheckedCheckboxes);
  });
});
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/gqcgwjq2/7/)

Also Id should have to be unique throughout the document. But here in our context that is not blocking you to see the expected result. Don't forget, Id always has to be unique. I spotted 2 distinct id's in your html. Correct it.

Comment: ".closest("div.row");" here write i need to pass my parent id like (main) is work ?

Comment: @Mgr That won't work, since that is holding both the `UL`. What is wrong in giving `div.row` ?

Comment: This should be affecting others ? because we have multiple div container same as but different functionality

Comment: It possible to make changes this script is only working for  parent id like (main) ?

Comment: @Mgr I can guarantee you. This won't affect other functionalities. You must read the documentation of  `closest`.

Comment: @Mgr If you want it for sure, then here is a version targeting `#main`  https://jsfiddle.net/gqcgwjq2/9/

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simpler version. Like i mentioned in the comment, you need to have different id assigned to `ul` ( i just name another one as `#function-collapse1`)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#function-collapse li,#function-collapse1 li').on('change',function() // delegate a change event on li items in ul 
    { $(this).closest('div.row').find('span.count-checked-checkboxes') // find the respective span element to display the count
    .text($(this).closest('ul').find('li input:checkbox:checked').length); 
    });
});
```

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/gqcgwjq2/11/

Comment: Did not understand the need of two `closest()` functions. `$(this).closest('ul').closest('div.row')` and `$(this).closest('div.row')` will select the same element don't you think?

Comment: Yes, you don't need 2 closest() functions. Closest works just like parent() so targeting the parent div.row would do the job perfectly. Updated the code.

Answer (score 0):

I created a loop for each ul you have:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#main ul").each(function() {
    var $ul = $(this);
    var $checkboxes = $ul.find('input[type="checkbox"]');
    $checkboxes.change(function() {
      var countCheckedCheckboxes = $checkboxes.filter(
        ':checked').length;
        $ul.parent().find('.count-checked-checkboxes').text(
        countCheckedCheckboxes);
        $ul.parent().find('#edit-count-checked-checkboxes').val(
        countCheckedCheckboxes);
    });
  });
});
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/4cnmmfwq/3/)

Comment: A better way to find a `parent` element with a particular `class` in `jQuery` is like this: `$ul.closest('.whateverParentClassIs').find('.count-checked-checkboxes').text(
        countCheckedCheckboxes);`. This way doesn't matter how far up the parent element is it will track back to that element.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is use this standard DOM method call:

```
 document.querySelector("input[type=checkbox]:checked").length;
```

And, to isolate the search to a specific section of the document, just use something like this:

```
 var part2 = document.querySelector("part2");
 part2.querySelector("input[type=checkbox]:checked").length;
```